# Not able to install npm packages after placed the private `.npmrc` file in Azure

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, devops, .npmrc

I'm not able to install packages from npm, since I have placed a .npmrc file for install a private library. 
This library is hosted by azure work space. 
So i just placed the new config file to install. And it works fine in localhost.

How can i keep 2 registry in nprmc file, one for private and another one of npm registry?

```
error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mm-core - Not found
```

mm-core is my private library hosted in azure, without my .npmrc file i receive this error.

With .npmrc file npm packages can't be installed.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

It actually should work if you follow the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) correctly. And we don't need to keep 2 registry in nprmc file, one for private and another one of npm registry.

**Solution:**

Keep the `.npmrc` file which presents the azure devops artifacts feed. And sign-in the azure devops web portal to configure the feed settings:

[image]

In feed settings, go `Upstream sources` and make sure you have `npmjs` as `Upstream source`. If it not exists, click the `Add upstream source` to add `npmjs`.

[image]

Then you only need to hold one registry for private library. If the package is not found in your private feed, since we've configured `npmjs` as `upstream source`, it will fetch the missing package there automatically!

More details about magic upstream source please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer.
This is my current error:
http://prntscr.com/rcgii2

I have the library avaliable using upstream source in Azure
http://prntscr.com/rcgj32

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but can you share more details about your [npm task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops)? I need to make sure how you define the task.(yaml or UI?) Please make sure you select azure devops feed as source.

Comment: My issue currently is this.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/943181/cant-npm-install-in-azure-with-pipeline-and-outsid.html

Comment: So you're using the feed from another project? Navigate to that feed=>Permissions=>Add user/groups=>Add CurrentProject build service to check if it helps. And please select `Registry I select here` instead of in my .npmrc file to check. Let me know if it helps :)